# common header issue in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with common header in react js.
Currently login route is displaying common header and i dont want to show  on my login page. If i go to contacts page than its showing common header which is perfect

```
import "./styles/App.scss";
import Navbar from "./components/elements/Navbar";
import Contacts from "./components/contacts/Contacts";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AddContact from "./components/contacts/AddContact";
import EditContact from "./components/contacts/EditContact";
import Login from "./components/login/Login";
import Logout from "./components/logout/Logout";


function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
        {props.location.pathname !== '/login' ? <Navbar/> : null}
          <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="py-3">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Contacts } />
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={ Logout } />
                <Route exact path="/contacts/add" component={ AddContact } />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/contacts/edit/:id"
                  component={ EditContact }
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V0qi.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to create **Links** in `NavBar`, not **declare** the *Routes*:

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="py-3">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Contacts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/contacts/add" component={AddContact} />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/contacts/edit/:id"
                component={EditContact}
              />
            </Switch>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

**NavBar:**

```
function Navbar() {
  const someId = 123 // example
  return (
   <>
    <Link to="/">Login</Link>
    <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>
    <Link to="/contacts/add">Add Contacts</Link>
    <Link to={`/contacts/edit/${someId}`}>Edit Contact</Link>
   </>

  )
}
```

After this, you are most likely to be looking for authentication. I recently wrote an answer on [authenticated or protected routes i.e. `PrivateRoute`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783231/2873538).

Also, note that [All children of a Switch should be Route or Redirect elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785774/2873538)

Comment: I have modify my code. Please check attach image

Comment: Its Solved! Thanks ajeet for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can only show the `<Navbar/>` when it's not the login page and you need to keep the login page inside the `switch` for the pages to work.

```
return (
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          {props.location.pathname !== '/login' ? <Navbar/> : null}
          <div className="container">
            <div className="py-3">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Contacts } />
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={ Logout } />
                <Route exact path="/contacts/add" component={ AddContact } />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/contacts/edit/:id"
                  component={ EditContact }
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
```

Comment: Make sure you take in the props for the component. `function App (props){}`

Comment: Error is changed now -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the whole component please. You should have props if you're using react router which it looks like you are

Comment: I have modified my question and also attached an image

Comment: Console.log your props and try and access the pathname and then use that to show the navbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230349/discussion-between-david-kohli-and-sean-reilly).