# React router doesnt reach redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page that has tabs on it. When I navigate to the page on my app I push to the base app. Ie. "/profile".

This is my profile component, the page that gets called.

```
<Profile>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/feed`} component={Feed} />
        
       
        {profileId !== null && (
          <>
            <Route exact path={`${path}/friends`} component={Friends} />
            <Route exact path={`${path}/locations`} component={Locations} />
            <Route exact path={`${path}/blockedlist`} component={BlockedList} />
          </>
        )}
        <Redirect from={path} to={`${path}/feed`} />
      </Switch>
    </Profile>
```

The redirect never gets run. When I remove the check if `profileId !== null` then it works. Basically when I load the page it will be at path `/profile` then this component should handle the redirect to `/feed` on initial load.

Comment: Right now it just stays at /profile and doesnt redirect automatically

Comment: It seems like a problem when using react fragments <></> it doesnt work in a switch. Any workarounds?

Comment: Switch can only have Route as a direct children. You can remove conditional and fragments and keep all routes exposed. Redirect should catch if none of the prior route matches.

Comment: You could return and spread (`...`) an array of react elements (e.g. routes) rather than wrapping them in a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to avoid wrapping an element (like with these Route's), you can spread an array of JSX elements instead, like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${path}/feed`} component={Feed} />
  {...(profileId !== null ? [
    <Route exact path={`${path}/friends`} component={Friends} key='friends' />,
    <Route exact path={`${path}/locations`} component={Locations} key='locations' />,
    <Route exact path={`${path}/blockedlist`} component={BlockedList} key='blockedlist' />
  ]: [])}
  <Redirect from={path} to={`${path}/feed`} />
</Switch>
```

Broken down, what this is doing is:

```
{
  ...( // The spread operator will expand the array it's given into its components
    conditional ? // Check your condition
      [routes]: // If it's true, return the routes
      [] // If not, return no routes
  )
}
```

Since it's returning an array into the render function, each item should have a `key` (Which is used by react to optimise the re-renders) so I've set each route to have part of it's path name as the key as these should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

**All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements**. See the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node).

So, you can refactor your nested routes (in `Profile` component) like this:

```
function Profile() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch()
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/feed`} component={Feed} />
      <Route
        render={(props) =>
          profileId !== null ? (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={`${path}/friends`} component={Friends} />
              <Route exact path={`${path}/locations`} component={Locations} />
              <Route exact path={`${path}/blockedlist`} component={BlockedList} />
            </Switch>
          ) : (
            <Redirect to={`${path}/feed`} />
          )
        }
      />
      <Redirect to={`${path}/feed`} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

#### Edit:

You can also add a redirect at last inside inner i.e. 2nd `Switch` above so that if user enter `/profile` and `profileId` is *valid*, it will redirect to `/profile/friends`:

```
...
<Redirect to={`${path}/friends`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your switch statements with BrowserRouter object and remove fregments `<>` and use `div` try this;

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom' 
<Profile>
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/feed`} component={Feed} />
        
       
        {profileId !== null && (
          <div>
            <Route exact path={`${path}/friends`} component={Friends} />
            <Route exact path={`${path}/locations`} component={Locations} />
            <Route exact path={`${path}/blockedlist`} component={BlockedList} />
          </div>
        )}
        <Redirect from={path} to={`${path}/feed`} />
      </Switch>
</Router> 
 </Profile>
```