# Show Sidebar Navigation only at Home using React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I made a Sidebar with navigation to 'home' and 'search' pages. But, what I want is that, I only need to show the Sidebar only on the 'home' page but *not* on the 'search' page. Here is what I have now: 
`App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import SideBar from "./components/SideBar";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Search from "./screens/Search";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {    
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
    <Switch>
      <SideBar />
      <Route exact path="/home">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/search">
        <Search />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But, it shows the Sidebar on both the pages.

#### Edit:

I don't want the sidebar to re-render when the route changes. In the Sidebar there are links to 'Home' and 'Search' pages. I only want those pages to render and re-render.

Comment: You should use `sidebar` under the `switch`, then you can use `./sidebar` where do you want

Comment: Can you please find the updated question. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that all children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements. See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785774/2873538) post. And, if you want to show `<SideBar />` component only at `<Home />`, you can simply keep it inside the `"/home"` Route:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home"> {/* Here */}
            <SideBar />
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/search">
            <Search />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/foo">
            <Foo />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-only-at-home-4l6ru?file=/src/App.js).

PS: You should have only one `Router` in your app, or it will soon become an issue due to *two* React-Router-Contexts available in your app.